# Code::Blocks 10.05 Undefined reference to function

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm currently doing simple class example using Code::Blocks IDE 10.04. On creating new class I encounter `undefined reference to myClass::myClass()` error. Help me on figuring the error.

myclass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass();
     void showMessage();
        virtual ~myClass();
    protected:
    private:
    string myString;
    int integer;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

myclass.cpp:

```
#include "E:\IOE\VII\Elective-DM\Assignment 2\myClass.h"

myClass::myClass()
{
    //ctor
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    //dtor
}
void myClass::showMessage()
{
    cout<<"Enter the number ";
    cin>>integer;
    cout<<"Enter the String ";
    cin>>myString;
    cout<<"\nInterger you enter is :-"<<integer<<" and String you enter is "<<myString<<endl;

}
```

sinpleClass.cpp:

```
#include<E:\IOE\VII\Elective-DM\Assignment 2\myClass.h>
int main()
{
    myClass myClassObj;
    myClassObj.showMessage();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use absolute paths to header files... ever. This is most likely also the problem, since the path has "Assignment 2" in it.

Comment: @StoryTeller I used according to link [here](http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingchyne/2011/03/codeblocks-failed-to-find-the-header-file/)

Comment: It's a workaround, not a solution. Furthermore, it was a mistake on their part to even offer that workaround. Don't do it.

Comment: I have not used Codeblocks for years so I do not remember the details on how it builds projects. However is myclass.cpp included in your project's source files?

Comment: Looks like a source file / project management issue.  Is your `myclass.cpp` part of the project?  Is it passed to the Linker?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no... I just tried to add class on snipleClass.cpp and it make header file and cpp file ... I just tried to add new class

Comment: @Pattinson, But do you have a project active, or is it just separate files?

Comment: @chris First I create `snipleClass.cpp` file then add class to it... no project active...

Comment: @Pattinson, Well, that would be your problem. No project means no linking when you hit build.

Comment: @chris Should we have to create to add class on file or not?

Comment: @Pattinson, Unless you do your own linking, you'll need a project any time you use a cpp file without a `main` in it, as is the implementation file in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is occurs due to the `linking error`.Later I create new project (according to [chris comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) above on question) and add class to it the project compile successfully.